# Information management retention policy not working on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, information-management, retention, archive

I have a custom list on SharePoint Online that a customer's maintenance crew uses to log service calls. We recently migrated them from wss 3.0 to SharePoint Online and discovered the 5000 item threshold. To remedy this we have created archive lists that we would move older list items too using an information management policy.

Since you can't move list items to another location, I created a 2010 workflow that well create a copy of the item on the archive list and then delete from the main list. I setup a new retention policy (see below), it would active when the work date was one month old and then it would active the archive workflow. However, for the last 3 months this job has not been running.

What do I need to change to get this retention policy to activate after an item is 1 month old from the work date field?

[image: Information Management Policy Setup]

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my issue. I was misreading how the SharePoint 2010 Workflows worked.
I originally thought you were supposed to use the Workflow with the lastest date `i.e Archive Workflow Service Call Log (Previous Version:6/9/2017 3:30:58 PM)` but to get the workflow to work I just needed to use the `Archive Workflow Service Call Log` without the previous version ending.